# SentenceTransformer Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tensor, huggingface, sentence-transformers

I'm using google colab to try this and I download the model for sentenceTransformers from huggingface hub using snapshot_download. For the model I'm using all-MiniLM-L6-v2

When I load the model from the repo that I have downloaded to my drive in the same runtime, it works perfectly.

but when I restart the runtime, and load the model again using the same directory that I use before, error appears. And the error is "Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory /content/drive/MyDrive/Generative_AI/NLP/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/."

what should i do?

```
#This is how I download the model
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
snapshot_download(repo_id="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
                   local_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/Generative_AI/NLP/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")


#This how I load the model
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Generative_AI/NLP/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_dir)
```

I tried to restart the runtime again and the error still appear. It turns out that I need to download and load the model in the same runtime, it means that i have to download every new runtime. But I want to download the model just once

Comment: I assume you are referring to disconnecting / deleting the runtime, in which case any local files created in Colab will also be removed? If so, yes, you'd need to download the model again each time or investigate persistent storage options like mounting Google Drive or using GCP.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mainly caused by transformers version. I would recommend installing transformers==4.32.0 or higher.

```
pip install -U transformers
```